# SQLCE: Why I get "duplicate value" error? The field is identity enabled?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce, sql-server-ce-4

In my query I don't use primary key field because identity setting is enabled.

```
   string sql = @"
                  INSERT INTO [tblTemplates] (personID, hash, data) 
                      VALUES (@personID, @hash, @data)";

   cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, cn);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personID", newTemplate.personID);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hash", newTemplate.templateHash);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", newTemplate.templateData);

   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Randomly I can or cannot insert a record then **an exception thrown**:

> A duplicate value cannot be inserted into a unique index.
>   [ Table name = tblTemplates,Constraint name = PK_*tblTemplates*_templateID
>   ]

**This is the table schema:**

```
-- Script Date: 26.08.2011 10:37  - Generated by ExportSqlCe version 3.5.1.5
CREATE TABLE [tblTemplates] (
  [templateID] int NOT NULL  IDENTITY (1,1)
, [hash] nvarchar(100) NOT NULL
, [data] image NOT NULL
, [personID] int NOT NULL
);
GO
ALTER TABLE [tblTemplates] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK__tblTemplates__templateID] PRIMARY KEY ([templateID]);
GO
CREATE INDEX [IDX_tblTemplates_personID] ON [tblTemplates] ([personID] ASC);
GO
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [UQ__tblTemplates__templateID] ON [tblTemplates] ([templateID] ASC);
GO
```

Why I get this error?

Comment: Because the PK column can never have duplicate entries. But i am sure your expecting much more than this, but from your question its not clear.

Comment: Is this code the only one that writes in the table? Or might there be other people/applications writing it? Was the table empty when you started or was there any data in it (maybe imported from an older application's DB)

Comment: You don't need UQ__tblTemplates__templateID because a primary key *is* unique.

Comment: also, if your application is multi-threaded this may be a [bug in SQL CE](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/641518/sql-ce-4-0-entity-framework-a-duplicate-identity-key-error-while-inserting-in-multi-threading-application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It seems like a bug!](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/641518/sql-ce-4-0-entity-framework-a-duplicate-identity-key-error-while-inserting-in-multi-threading-application)

Workaround: Converting field data type from int to uniqueidentifier works.

My workaround attempts:

**Attempt #1:** *Same connection*

```
        bool executed = false;
        int counter = 0;

        while (!executed)
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                succes = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SERVER> (Error) Exception in AddTemplate() {0},{1}", ex.Source, ex.Message);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }

            counter++;

        }
```

**Result:** This seems like an endless loop.

**Attempt #2:** *New connection*

```
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                succes = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SERVER> (Error) Exception in AddTemplate() {0},{1}", ex.Source, ex.Message);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                AddTemplate(newTemplate); //Warning: Recursive call!
            }
```

**Result:** This try helped after a few recursive calls.

Comment: Switching away from auto-assigned Ids and using uniqueidentifier/Guid seems to have 'fixed' this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I used `IDENTITY_INSERT` on my table like

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON;
-- some identity insert on MyTable
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF;
```

After this, all inserts on `MyTable` throw "duplicate value" error.

Solution to this problem was

```
var cmd = Connection.CreateCommand();                
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX([Id] ) + 1 from [MyTable]";
object i = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
if (i != null && i is int)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ALTER COLUMN [Id] IDENTITY (" + i + ",1)";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```